# How to add new document in MongoDB if it doesn't exists?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongodb. I'm trying to insert data in mongodb through mongoose. But I'm facing issues.

I've attached the image about how I am expecting my data to be inserted.

[image]

Now here is my Schema.

```
const ticketApplicationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({



    ticketId: {
        type: ObjectId,
        text: String,
        required: true,
        ref: "Ticket",
      },
      applications:[{
          userId:{
              type:ObjectId,
              default:"adsfadsfasdf",
              ref:"User"
          },
          answers:{
              type:Array
          }
      }]

})
```

And my Insert Data Function

```
const insertTicket = (ticketId, ticketObject) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      ticketApplicationSchema
        .findOneAndUpdate(
          { ticketId },
          
          ticketObject,

          {
            new: true,
            upsert: true,
          }
        )
        .then((data) => resolve(data))
        .catch((error) => {
          // console.log(error);
          reject(error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      // reject(error);
    }
  });
};
```

Please help me where am I doing wrong?

In short, tell me how to add on the applications data (user and answers) as an array to applications object. I want the data to be inserted in the same ticketId. When I re-run the code, it just replace the current data instead of adding new object of user and ticket.

Here is the image

[image]

For example, my ticketId is abcd1234. Now multiple users can submit their answers to that.

Comment: Difficult to understand what you are expecting man. Can you be a little more clear.

Comment: For the first, thanks for paying attentions to my question @TusharShahi.

I want to insert one object that will contain the userId and the 3 answers submitted by the user. The object will be inserted as an array to applications. 

In other words: 

applications: [
{
user: userId,
answers: ["a","b","c"]
},

{
user: userId,
answers: ["a","b","c"]
},

{
user: userId,
answers: ["a","b","c"]
}
]

I think it is clear. If not do let me know I will explain further. Thanks.

Comment: But ticketId is same, and inside applications you are adding users with their answers?

Comment: See, my project is: There will be a list of tickets, the user will click on the ticket, and will give answers. Now I want to store that in my database. So I want to add the ticketId and then the userId along with his answer. And since there will be multiple users, so I want to add them in an array.

Comment: This is how I am expecting the data that will be added https://pasteboard.co/K3YTTKn.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your newArray in a new object you can simply [push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) that object like this :

```
ticketApplicationSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
   { ticketId }, 
   { $push: 
   { applications: newUserObject  } 
   }).then((data) => resolve(data))
        .catch((error) => {
          // console.log(error);
          reject(error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      // reject(error);
    }
  });
```